# Flutter crossAxisAlignment vs mainAxisAlignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm confused about `crossAxisAlignment` and `mainAxisAlignment`. Can anyone please explain it in simple words?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

**For Row:**

`mainAxisAlignment` = Horizontal Axis
`crossAxisAlignment` = Vertical Axis

[image]

---

**For Column:**

`mainAxisAlignment` = Vertical Axis
`crossAxisAlignment` = Horizontal Axis

[image]

[Image source](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#aligning-widgets)

Answer (score 17):

This two pictures are clear to show the meaning of MainAxisAlignment and CrossAxisAlignment.
[image]
[image]

[(Pictures are from Network)](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout#aligning-widgets)

Answer (score 6):

`Row`/`Column` are associated to an axis:

- Horizontal for `Row`
- Vertical for `Column`

`mainAxisAlignment` is how items are aligned on that axis. `crossAxisAlignment` is how items are aligned on the other axis.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Oncept]

Depends on you how you wanna put your content on screen. we need to use mainAxis & CrossAxis alignment properties.

For more basic layout concepts: https://flutter.dev/docs/codelabs/layout-basics

Answer (score 4):

When you use a `Row`, its children are laid out in a row, which is horizontally. So a `Row`'s main axis is horizontal. 
Using `mainAxisAlignment` in a `Row` lets you align the row's children horizontally (e.g. left, right). 
The cross axis to a `Row`'s main axis is vertical. So using `crossAxisAlignment` in a `Row` lets you define, how its children are aligned vertically.

In a `Column`, it's the opposite. The children of a column are laid out vertically, from top to bottom (per default). So its main axis is vertical. This means, using `mainAxisAlignment` in a `Column` aligns its children vertically (e.g. top, bottom) and `crossAxisAlignment` defines how the children are aligned horizontally in that Column.

Answer (score 2):

In a **column**,

- to center(or align) **vertically**, **mainAxisAlignment** is used.
- to center(or align) **horizontally**, **crossAxisAlignment** is used.

In a **row**,

- to center(or align) **horizontally**, **mainAxisAlignment** is used.
- to center(or align) **vertically**, **crossAxisAlignment** is used.

Answer (score 0):

In **Row** Main Axis Alignment run horizontally and Cross Axis Alignment run vertically.
In **Column** Main Axis Alignment run vertically and Cross Axis Alignment run Horizontally.