# Full width with column children not working

Tags: flutter

I have a row with 2 children, 1 child is a column containing another 2 items, and the second-row item has an expanded widget with a button inside it. I'm trying to make both row items full width.

I added an `expanded` widget to both children. The result for the row child with only 1 item worked perfectly, but the result of the row item that had a nested column there, the `expanded` widget made its height full screen, while keeping the width small.

How can I make both row childrens width 50% and their height 100px?

Here are the results I would like to have:
[image]

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: If you could include some kind of visual, it'd great to understand the problem and the goal.

Comment: @JigarPatel Ya, It was confusing. Thanks for pointing that out! Just added images

Comment: Did you try to wrap just your button inside the Expanded widget?

Comment: Set crossAxisAlignment to CrossAxisAlignment.stretch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850149/flutter-crossaxisalignment-vs-mainaxisalignment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this..

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text('Some other text'),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Button'),
                onPressed: (){},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Button'),
            onPressed: (){},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```