# How to align image along with text in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

`enter code here`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQx49.jpg)how to reduce the vertical distance between widgets, I even haven't used any sizebox or padding then why this spacing happened, and also if I tried using "crossAxisAlignment" to start only text moved up but not image. why?

[image: and this happens when I wrap it with alignment]

```
                Wrap(
                 alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset("assets/images/bline.png",
                        color: Colors.white, width: 150),
                    Text(
                      "or login with",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.oregano().fontFamily,
                        fontSize: 25,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Image.asset("assets/images/bline.png",
                        color: Colors.white, width: 150),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SocialCard(
                      icon: "assets/icons/google.svg",
                      press: () {},
                    ),
                    SocialCard(
                      icon: "assets/icons/facebook.svg",
                      press: () {},
                    ),
                    SocialCard(
                      icon: "assets/icons/phone.svg",
                      press: () {},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: attach your code not image

Comment: Try with Align or positioned widgets refer this links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716571/how-to-align-single-widgets-in-flutter  or  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-positioned-widget/

Comment: A warm welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and share your code snippet to reproduce the errors.

Comment: Try using mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min in Column. Still issue shows your image might have padding or extra space vertically !

Comment: Naveen Avidi , still nothing happened and I already reviewed it more than 10 times no extra spacing was provided

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `Column` as a parent of your `Row` widgets?
if yes, you should set:

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment. //use different formats to find one that best suits for your purpose
```

In general, you should use `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment` for each `Row` and `Column` to align their children in each direction.
see this [Flutter crossAxisAlignment vs mainAxisAlignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850149/flutter-crossaxisalignment-vs-mainaxisalignment).

Comment: mainAxisAlignment only moves text up not the side image

Comment: only work on text

Comment: It works with all widgets. However, there are some parameters you should set for some widgets, for example, you should make sure about its size.

Answer (score 0):

You just replace your `Column` with `wrap`

**EDITED**

```
Wrap(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
              Image.asset("assets/images/bline.png",
                color: Colors.green,width: 120,),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Text(
                "or login with",
                style: TextStyle(
                  //  fontFamily: GoogleFonts.oregano().fontFamily,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Image.asset("assets/images/bline.png",
                color: Colors.green,width: 120,),
            ],),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SocialCard(
                  icon: "assets/icons/google.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
                SocialCard(
                  icon: "assets/icons/facebook.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
                SocialCard(
                  icon: "assets/icons/phone.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Comment: wait m trying to attach code here .actually m new on stack so facing lots of issues on posting code

Comment: please review it I edited the code also let me know why these 2 rows why automatically created such wide space without providing any alignment or spacing

Comment: gimme some moment, i will check

Comment: @jasmine please have a look i edited my answer

Comment: still, no change, should I send you the whole code so you can review it and I also get to know whether I actually used any extra space or not

Comment: from my end it's working, you bind your code with two row inside `wrap`

Comment: no just the 1st row (image ,text , image) inside wrap

Comment: you also wrap 2nd row, otherwise just paste my code i hope it works for you

Comment: i did the same have only copy pase your code

Comment: 1st row (image ,text , image),  2nd row( 3 images) both two in under wrap

Comment: or share your git  link

Answer (score 0):

If you've used Column.
maybe you should set the parameter
`mainAxisSize` и `mainAxisAlignment`

To change the spacing between widgets you can use `SizedBox` for fixed margins or `Spacer` to fill the remaining free space.
You can also wrap your widgets in `Expanded`.
And set `Flex` option for `Expanded` and `Spacer`

```
Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          widget_1,
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          widget_2,
          Spacer(),
          widget_3,
        ],
      );
```